# Set some web directories as restricted directories

Tags: php, apache

I am doing PHP web application, with Apache.

There are a few configuration files ( like App.yml) whose content I don't want to expose to users under whatsoever circumstances. Is there anyway that I can tweak my Apache setting so that these files won't be available when hostile users query for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to place the files outside of your document root.
If that's not possible, you can deny access to them in apache .conf file (or a .htaccess file) with

```
<Directory /path/to/dir>
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.htaccess` file in that directory and place in it

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

You can also do this if you only want to block one file.

```
<Files filenamehere>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```